Help with a model to predict the number of leads of upcoming cohort
We are an online school with new cohorts starting on the first day of each month.
In the (approx) 45 days leading up to the 1st day, we receive a report every twice a week that tells us the number of leads we have received so far for the upcoming cohort.
I've organised this data into a table with 2 columns: a) days until the start of the cohort and b) the number of leads so far. We have this data for 9 cohorts.
My goal is to create a model or tool, that will allow us in the future when a leads report comes in to predict the final leads that we will receive in that cohort. The inputs of the model would be a) days until the start of the cohort and b) the number of leads so far.
I created a Logistic Growth Model and obtained the following equation
Predicted Final Leads = Leads so far x ( 1 + exp(0.1436651145 x ( Days before start - 18.47647343)))
I then tested this model by inputing some of the historical data but unfortunately the result was always off by big margins (e.g 10%).
​
Am I making any mistakes? Do you have any tips?
​
PS: here is a link to the data: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/5LcP0SEn

Is logistic growth the best fit? (Is your fitted formula even logistic growth?)

Yes, that's correct.
